# First order ordinary differential equation about fish populations in a lake.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this question which has me stumped, here's the problem.

A lake is stocked with a fish population of size $ N(t)$ at time t. Initially the population is $N(0) = N_0$ the evolution of he population is given by this ODE:$$ \frac{dN}{dt}=\frac{aN}{b}(b-N)$$ Where a and b are both positive constants.
a) find N(t)
b) what is the behavior of N(t) and t tend to infinity

So the way the question is set up makes me think its somehow separable here's what i've tried
Rearranging this gets me:
$$\int \frac{1}{N(b-N)}dN=\int \frac{a}{b}dt$$
Partial fractions on LHS give:
$$\int \frac{1}{b(b-N)}+\frac{1}{bN} dN=\int \frac{a}{b}dt$$
evaluating the integrals and simplifying:
$$\frac{1}{b}ln(\frac{N}{b-N})=\frac{a}{b}t+C$$
some more fiddling:
$$\frac{N}{b-N}=Ae^{at}$$
where A is a postive constant.
So i can mess around further getting this sort of thing $N(t)=\large{\frac{Abe^{at}}{1-Ae^{at}}}$ (thanks to martin for picking up the sign error that should be $N(t)=\large{\frac{Abe^{at}}{1+Ae^{at}}}$)thing i'm missing. I've tried subbing in the initial conditions but it really doesn't help i get something no nice looking for my constant A as a result. hopefully you guys can see it. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did is almost right (sign mistake when solving for $N$). You can "prettify" your $N$ a bit by writing
$$
N(t)=\frac{Ab}{e^{-at}+A}
$$
Zill-Wright (7th Edition, at least) call your equation the *logistic equation*.

When you introduce the initial condition, you get 
$$
N_0=\frac{Ab}{1+A},
$$
so 
$$
A=\frac{N_0}{b-N_0}.
$$
Now $N$ looks like 
$$
N(t)=\frac{N_0b(b-N_0)}{e^{-at}+N_0/(b-N_0)}
=\frac{N_0b}{(b-N_0)e^{-at}+N_0}.
$$
Or even 
$$
N(t)=\frac{b}{(b/N_0-1)e^{-at}+1}.
$$

Comment: Hi thanks alot for the soulution really helped , could you explain what happens as t tends to infinity? so like the e part goes to 0 right but then i have a negative population size ?

Comment: You made a mistake when solving for $N$. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you made a sign mistake..
$$\int \frac{1}{N(b-N)}dN=\int \frac{a}{b}dt$$
$$\frac 1 b(\int \frac {dN}{N}+\int\frac {dN}{b-N})=\frac ab t+k$$
$$\frac 1 b(\int \frac {dN}{N}-\int\frac {dN}{N-b})=\frac ab t+k$$
$$ \ln|\frac  {N}{N-b}|=a t+K$$
$$ \frac  {N}{N-b}=Ke^{a t}$$
$$ {N}(1-Ke^{at})=-bKe^{a t}$$
$$ {N}=\frac {-bKe^{a t}} {(1-Ke^{at})}=\frac {b} {1-Ke^{-at}}$$
$$N(0)=\frac b {1-K} \to K=1-\frac b {N_0} \to N=\frac {b} {1+(\frac b {N_0} -1)e^{-at}}$$